# In LaTeX distribution, which files are the mandatory files to compile a minimal LaTeX input file?

Tags: distributions

Assume I want to create an application working together with LaTeX compiler behind the scene. For the sake of simplicity, assume I also use `minimal` document class and no package imported.

At the final stage, I want to deploy this application to a computer with no LaTeX system installed. This scenario forces me to make the installer get shipped with the LaTeX compiler.

Shortly speaking, which files (in LaTeX distribution) are needed as minimal as possible?

Comment: @xport: I suppose that you have to use the full path to `mkjobtexmf`. Don't know how the files in Windows are found. You can also try `perl mkjobtexmf ...`

Comment: @xport: in Linux it is a link to the perl file `../texmf/scripts/mkjobtexmf/mkjobtexmf.pl` Do you have that file?

Comment: @xport: in TeXLive2010 for windows it is present. I cannot say more here for other distributions. Maybe that you have to install it.

Comment: @xport: just tried it with TeXLive under Windows and in diffrence to Linux it creates a file `<file>????.fls` with a list of all used files.

Comment: @xport: ah I see. It couldn't create a directory. Write protected directory? And the contents of the created file list, is it ok?

Comment: I have almost exactly the same need, and have offered a bounty. I'm also curious how might I package my own LaTeX distribution (do I just copy the required files?).

Comment: It is strange practise to recommend installing perl for windows users. Although it is possible, Microsoft recommends Power Shell built into all recent versions of Windows. Since Microsoft always provides backward compatibility, Power Shell should also run .js, .wsf, .vb scripts as well. They provides access to all internal windows methods and properties. You can write a scripts that edits, say, MS World document. But for the sake of what?

Comment: @Igor: There is no Microsoft WORLD. :D

Answer (score 15):

make a testfile and run it with:

```
mkjobtexmf --jobname <file> --cmd-tex <latex>
```

`<file>` is your source file `<latex>` is your LaTeX command, e.g. `pdflatex` or simply `latex`.
The *Perl* program mkjobtexmf creates a directory `<file>.mjt` which is a compatible texmf directory with all loaded files of your example.

If you are running windows then you'll need an installed Perl, e.g. from
[http://www.activestate.com/perl/](http://www.activestate.com/perl/.)

However, I never used it under Windows, with Linux it is very useful.

Comment: it seems mkjobtexmf does not include the .fmt file?

Comment: @Taco: from a run: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 voss users 56  4. Jan 16:10 latex.fmt -> /home/voss/.texlive2010/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt`

Comment: Ah ok, it seems to only work if the .fmt is inside a pre-conceived directory. I get a `Failed` line because the .fmt is not where `mkjobtexmf` expects it to be.

Comment: @Taco: drop Heiko a line, if you feel that it is a missing feature.

Comment: One time that I have been created the folder.mjt how can I execute pdflatex on my .tex document from that folder?

Comment: I am also interested in this process. If I share that folder with other computer without `pdflatex`, how to proceed?

Comment: @Sigur: every program can use that folder. However with every run the files will be overwritten

Comment: @Herbert, I'd like to zip that folder and send to some body together with some TeX binary file. Is it possible to run `pdflatex` binary with that folder without installing other TeX stuffs on the computer?

Comment: @Sigur: In general yes. You have to set `TEXMFHOME=...` to that directory. However, I do not tried it with binaries. Maybe that they should be in an executable directory.

Comment: @Herbert, thanks. I am having progress on that. I discovered the portable installation version of TL. It works well.