# Portable minimal distribution

Tags: distributions, portability

Are there any portable minimal latex/xelatex distributions? I know of MikTeX portable, but at 130MBs it is far from minimal. Alternatively, can I easily make my own distribution?

What I would like to have is:

- Ability to compile a pre-defined type of XeTeX document
- Just the required packages included
- Size under 5MB, ideally under 2MB

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want just XeTeX (_i.e._ with a plain-like format) or does it also need to have LaTeX?

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I would much prefer LaTeX.

Comment: I may be wrong, but your size requirements sound very optimistic to me. Are you really that constrained by the space available to you?

Comment: @Anthony Labarre: Most likely, no. I would prefer it to be as minimal as possible. I assumed that TeX is "small" because it was completed in 1989. And then I assumed that LaTeX "can't be much larger".

Comment: @ipavlic: But you've for XeLaTeX, which is bigger on any system, and 'modern' LaTex is a lot bigger than say LaTeX 2.09 (core only) in 1989!

Comment: @Joseph Wright: How big exactly are bare systems which can support XeLaTeX?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: You are right about the sizes of USB sticks, but that is not what I am looking for. I stated in my question that I do know of MiKTeX portable, which is around 15 times smaller and thus more appropriate by my criteria.

Comment: Are 130Mb really large considering that virtually everyone has fast broadband internet nowadays and that you can pick up a 16GB pen drive for a mere 20 quid?

Comment: @Martin H: For my purposes, it is. If my requirements can be satisfied, great. If not, what's the next best option? I am perfectly satisfied with an answer 20MBs, 50MBs (or 130MBs) if that is really the smallest size possible. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your effort. Still, imagine somebody wanted to convince you to use Word instead of LaTeX: "but do you really need excellent line-breaking and so-called-nice-looking documents without wysiwyg in today's fast paced world?"

Comment: I'm using beside my miktex a rather bare development lua(la)tex (with the binaries from w32tex.org). The bin-folder contains also the format files and is about 10 MB large. To this you must add the space for fonts (luatex and xetex still needs TeX-fonts e.g. for math),  packages, tools like dvips (e.g. for pst-pdf), bibtex, makeindex/xindy, package manager, ...

I would say 5 MB is impossible today. 20 MB is very optimistic.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. So I'm guessing 25-30MBs is probably feasible. I do not need math fonts. Any pointers on what exactly do I need to download XeLaTeX?

Comment: Get either miktex portable or texlive portable, install it and then remove the things you don't need (in miktex you can  use the package manager to remove packages). - And I have no idea if 30MB is feasible, perhaps with the w32tex.org binaries but probably not with miktex. The miktex package with xetex binaries has a size of 14MB.

Comment: There exists a script that builds a distribution based on a single document. See   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8249/

Comment: I don't know whether this is the right place to tell, but I'd suggest trying Lout: http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lout (not a TeX, but very similar to it)

Comment: @Orbis: Sorry, but -1 from me. *lots* of things that do not actually relate to the question are smaller than a TeX distribution, but listing these does not amount to a usable answer.

Comment: @Tobi: OK! Do you have a better choice under 2Mb?

Comment: @Orbis: It is not the answer to my question but it is helpful to me. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Orbis: I converted your answer to a comment. I think it is better suited to be one. Thanks for you contribution.

Comment: It seems to me you also collapsed other answers into comments, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Summarising the various comments as an answer, the bottom line is that a target of 5 MB is unrealistic. For example, the Windows XeTeX binary on my system is 2.7 MB, while as Ulrike says

> The MiKTeX package with XeTeX binaries has a size of 14MB.

(On my Unix system, the XeTeX binary is 17.8 MB). You need of course in addition to XeTeX the `xdvipdfm` system (I'm not sure exactly how that is packaged up on different systems.)

As an absolute minimum, you need in addition to the XeTeX binary some structure for finding files (`kpsewhich` or MiKTeX's equivalent), basic fonts (Computer Modern and Latin Modern), then a basic LaTeX (the base/required/tools, plus whatever you feel is 'minimal'). That is all going to add up.

Looking at the existing small distributions, [BasicTeX (Mac-only)](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) is 92 MB and [MiKTeX basic](http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup) is 157 MB. You could try to build something like one of these yourself, but the most obvious way to proceed is

> Get either MiKTeX portable or TeX Live portable, install it and then
>   remove the things you don't need (in MiKTeX you can use the package
>   manager to remove packages).

(again from Ulrike's comment).

To get the size down, you should also look to remove all of the `doc` tree, as this tends to be quite big. Of course, you'll be left with no documentation, but it will be smaller.

Answer (score 14):

As a 13 years long LaTeX user, I managed to have my own minimal distribution extracted from TeXlive, in the way Joseph Wright described in his answer, and installed it on my personal directory on a server at work (on windows platform) so that it runs in any computer I'm connected with.

It consists of *pdflatex* + *bibtex8* + *makeindex* + *scite* + *sumatrapdf* and a few standard packages (*base* + *tools* + *graphics* + *geometry* + *titlesec* + *pgf* + *hyperref* and dependencies).

I also tweaked `fonttext.cfg`, `fontmath.cfg` and `preload.cfg` to have Latin Modern as default fonts so that I have no cm and ec fonts installed... All this stands in 30MB (~1300 files) so I can confirm that a standalone pdflatex system (without the editor, pdfviewer and extra package like pgf) stands in no more than 20MB. Surely *xelatex* and *lualatex* need more space because of bigger binaries.

Comment: Can you share your experience by explaining the steps? What parts are removed? @Bertrand Morel.

Comment: I'm interested in the instructions as well, even though it seems like @BertrandMorel is no longer visiting TeX.SE.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko, did you have any progress on doing this? I'm also interested. I want a way to compile only a single document, many times, in many computers.

Comment: @Sigur, no, but I looked at [SILE](https://github.com/simoncozens/sile) instead as it allows for more compact package.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko, thanks, but I would like to use Tikz package. So...

Comment: @Sigur Have a look at my reply. Basically, you can start by putting `your.tex` and `pdflatex.exe` in the same folder and keep adding `.dll, .fd, .sty, .cls, .pfb, .tfm, .clo, .map` files from a working distribution until `pdflatex.exe your.tex` successfully produces `your.pdf`. No subfolders required.

Answer (score 6):

I have also been wondering why this TeXLive thing is taking up so much space and what all of these files and directories are all about and which ones the program actually uses on my behalf.

So I just copied `pdflatex.exe` out of there and added files until I could compile a simple article with some math and different fonts in it:

```
%%hello.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\title{How to Structure a LaTeX Document}
\author{Someone}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract goes here...
...
\end{abstract}


\section{Structure}
This section's content...

\subsection{Top Matter}
This subsection's content...

\subsubsection{Article Information}
This subsubsection's content...

\emph{hello} hello $x^2, \mathbb R, \mathcal C, \mathfrak F, \int_0^1 \sin(x) \mathrm d x$

\end{document}
```

Turns out you just need, in addition to pdflatex.exe:

- some `.dll`s
- the `.sty` files for packages you use and dependencies of the packages you use
- Some `U*.fd` files to fix errors of the form `` LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/*/m/n' undefined ``
- `texmf.cnf`
- `<the documentclass>.cls`
- `size10.clo` (whatever this is)
- `.tfm` (font metric) and `.pfb` files for all the fonts you use (or plan to use, or a few more)
- `pdftex.map` which is a concatenation of all `.map` files for the fonts you use.

These files don't have to be in the standard latex folder structure. They can just be in the same folder as the `pdflatex` executable.

I have uploaded a **~10MB** (unpacked) folder containing all files necessary to run `pdflatex hello.tex` in it and have it produce `hello.pdf`:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iDTmFBQt8fFUSpOoJZWLw8TEai35awCj (it contains pdflatex.**exe** (from TeXLive2016), so Google Drive might tell you "contains executable code, download at your own risk")

If you try to compile something more complicated, you should be able to copy over the necessary files from your full TeXLive installation to make this minimum installation capable of compiling it too.

---

That said, if you are on-the-go or in a low-resource environment but have an internet connection, you might prefer to use things like

- http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/latex.php
- https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php
- https://www.overleaf.com/
- https://papeeria.com/
- https://www.mathjax.org/

which might provide an API to compile some LaTeX for you.

Comment: This sounds super promising, and 10MB is mighty impressive. Too bad it's Windows only... =(

Comment: I am sure the same technique works on unix systems

Comment: I updated the link to my example, this still works on Windows 10 x64, though I did not try with newer texlive versions, don't see a reason why they would have changed things that made this "reduction technique" work though.

Answer (score 1):

Stripping Thierry Laronde's blazing fast TeX distribution, [KerTeX](http://www.kergis.com/en/kertex.html), you can get a **plain** TeX distribution in under **2MB**.

0) The `tex` executable is `1,229,008` bytes (after running `strip` on it). (I've modified the C sources a bit so your size may vary slightly.)

1) The `plain.fmt` file is `541,382` bytes.

Total: `1,770,390` bytes.

2) The rest is just **fonts**.

I'm using a custom DVI driver (forked from `dvipng`), and this is all I need to **compile** `.tex` source code and **render** `.dvi` code.

---

Type 1 fonts can add a few MBs (since there's so many of them...), but you can keep the total under 2MB. Each Type 1 font is 2 files: a `.pfb` file and a `.tfm` file. Each Type 1 font is about `35,000` bytes in total. For example, I'm using these Type 1 fonts: `cmssbx10`, `cmssbx10`, `cmss10`, `cmssbx10`, `cmssi10`, `cmsl10`, `cmtt10`, `cmcsc10`, `cmmi10`, `cmsy10`, `cmbx10`, `eusm10`, `eusb10`, `eufm10`, `eufb10`, `cmr10`, `cmmi7`, `cmr7`.

The KerTeX `tex` executable (which compiles `.tex` source code into `.dvi`), and my DVI driver (which renders `.dvi` code to the screen and to images)  needs the `plain.fmt` file to work, and the `.pfb` and `.tfm` files for fonts. (Though I think `tex` only needs the TFM files?)

That's it.

(Actually KerTeX's `tex` executable also needs a `KXPATH` file in the fonts folder, for some reason, but it's only `6` bytes...)

(By the way, the KerTeX `tex` executable compiles small TeX files in about 2 milliseconds, so it's more than enough to compile and render `.tex` source in real time, since the DVI driver can be made pretty fast, too.)