# LaTeX custom distribution

Tags: xetex, distributions

I have two questions:

1. Is it legal to redistribute LaTeX in
   a commercial software?
2. if is, how do I make a minimal and portable distribution of plain latex and a few packages?

**Note**: I wish to use LaTeX by IPC in my program to print some numbers on sale factors. I would like to do this via LaTeX + XeLaTeX (if possible).

Thanks in advance

Comment: As for the second part of your question, you might take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/portable-minimal-distribution

Comment: Doesn't Scientific Workplace redistribute latex? They are a commercial software which requires latex, I am just not sure it comes bundled with it or whether you have to download separately, but I believe it all comes together.

Comment: Get a lawyer to interpret [the LPPL license](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt).

Comment: OK, I read license file... seems to be possible to redistribute. But Of course will ask a lawyer. I'll try and probably ask again about distribution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To not let this question unanswered, here's a CW answer, feel free to edit.

1. The legal part is completely answered by [The LaTeX Project Public License](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt).
2. See ipavlic's link: [Portable minimal distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/portable-minimal-distribution)