# pdflatex binaries for win32?

Tags: pdftex, windows

Is the a place where I can download up-to-date win32 binaries of pdflatex (including all other files needed)?

I don't need a GUI, just the plain .exe.

MikTex-portable contains a pdflatex.exe but also a lot of other stuff i don't need and copying it to a microSD-Card takes a lot of time because the filesystem has to create a lot of (small) files.

Instead of reckless deleting stuff from the Miktex directory i would like to use pdflatex from a trustworthy source and just add the packages i need.

Comment: Have you read [Portable minimal distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/portable-minimal-distribution)?

Comment: I suspect the best place to start in [w32tex](http://w32tex.org/), simply because MiKTeX's auto-install system will add to the overall size requirement. (w32tex is the source for the TeX binaries in TeX Live.) My CW answer in the linked question probably covers most of the rest of how I'd tackle this.

Comment: w32tex does look promising regarding the overall size but there are still a lot of files (>8k) wich slows down the copying to an SD-Card.

I will try to set up a portable LuaTex. In this tutorial it looks like there are just a few files needed to create a minimal LuaTex environment: http://www.readytext.co.uk/?p=642

Answer (score 3):

A trustworthy source is CTAN. There's a `system` directory, and a win32 directory below that. There you can choose your executable.

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32

An obvious choice is

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/w32tex

where you can find [pdftex-w32.tar.bz2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/w32tex/pdftex-w32.tar.bz2). This is the engine (binary), then you need a LaTeX format file, and I guess you would like to have the base classes and styles too, so download [latex.tar.bz2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/w32tex/latex.tar.bz2) as well.