# Essential files to run LaTeX

Tags: filesystem-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Portable minimal distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/portable-minimal-distribution)

Which files are essential to run LaTeX? Is possible for example, make a copy of these files and also of the packages used in my document to run pdfLaTeX without install all the TeXLive distribution?

I use TeXLive 2012 and Windows 8.

Comment: Related (duplicate?) question: [Portable minimal distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13649/2693)

Comment: Yes, very closely related, we can make additions to that earlier question and its answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`mkjobtexmf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mkjobtexmf) program to get all files used by a TeX job. It's included in TeXLive 2012 (at least on Linux).

Comment: As I understand it,  doesn't this copy just the package associated files and not the binaries used to compile them?

Comment: @AlanMunn: Yes. Getting all required binaries and their used shared libraries is a different problem. `:-)`