# Installing *just* TeX

Tags: tex-core, installing, linux

For a project, I intend to use TeX as a “backend” to layout and generate PDF, i. e., my program would emit core-TeX code to be immediately compiled. I think that means I just need `pdftex` or `xetex + dvipdf` and their minimal dependencies.

TeXLive, however, does not seem to account for such a use-case; even a minimal installation as described in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397174/minimal-texlive-installation) contains `tex`, `pdftex`, `luatex`, `bibtex`, various dvi drivers, and some other things that I don’t think are all strictly necessary.

Is it possible to achieve my goal without having to manually prune such an installation?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509026/87678 ?

Comment: Seriously: It's 2020 and you worry too much. Don't waste your time shrinking an installation from 1GB to 256MB.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to use TeX Live? E.g. if you're adventurous, [an answer on the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509026/48) (of which I'm the only upvoter for some reason) mentions KerTeX and a size of 2 MB. (Of course you can't get that small if you want pdfTeX or XeTeX.)

Comment: (I personally do sympathize with the idea, and find it smart.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute minimal TeX Live installation is `scheme-infraonly`, which really means it: you don't get anything beyond that necessary to allow `tlmgr` to run. You can then add packages one at a time: this needs a bit of experimentation even with an ultra-small set of requirements.

As you almost certainly want to avoid sources and documenation, you likely want a profile file saying

```
selected_scheme scheme-infraonly
option_doc 0
option_src 0
```

to be installed using

```
./install-tl --profile=texlive.profile
```

(using whatever name you've given the file).

The resulting installation is about 3.0 Mb according to `du -sh`. Adding pdfTeX using `tlmgr install pdftex`, which pulls in things like the Computer Modern fonts, etc., takes it to 25 Mb.

Comment: You could install just pdfTeX with no dependencies, but I think the ones that TeX Live lists are pretty much essential.

Comment: Thank you! This is closer to what I intended! Is tlmgr a hard dependency of pdftex though?

Comment: @Tau It's a dependency for TeX Live, but not pdfTeX itself; if you are on Windows, you could try out W32TeX, which supplies the pdfTeX binaries. That's installed using simple zip files.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110975/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-installing-just-tex).

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify Linux, the most minimal package available for Debian/Ubuntu is `texlive-base`, which comes in at nearly 75 MB.  If you don’t use an `apt` or `rpm` package, you would need to install `tlmgr` or another package manager to keep it updated.

It includes `pdftex`, `biblatex`, `luatex` (which you need to use `texlua`, e.g. for the `getnonfreefonts` installer to work), `metafont`, some fonts, color profiles, and glyph data.

Is there a practical need for the smallest installation possible?  Even USB flash drives have dozens of gigabytes of space.