# Distributable Tex application

Tags: pdftex, windows, plain-tex, minimal

I'm trying to write a very short .tex file which should read some images and text and create a report in pdf. Writing the tex is definitely not the problem.
The report will contain some text, and a big table with numbers and images (png). no equation or strange characters, no references or biblio.
My problem is that this tex should be then run also on other machines which might not have installed any tex distribution.

**So my question is: is there any way to run pdflatex.exe without having installed all MikTex(or other distributions)?**

I've found a very similar question here:
[Redistributing pdfLaTeX as a part of an application](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21264/redistributing-pdflatex-as-a-part-of-an-application)
where one promising advice was to use plain Tex instead of LaTeX:

> "My advice: use plain TeX instead of LaTeX. You will need far fewer files that way, and that means you can (usually) have everything you need as part of your software. I have done this on various occasions, and could usually get by with only a couple of megabytes of extra stuff (pdftex.exe, plain format and a macro file, and a few fonts)."

Anyone has experience about it? What kind of files I would need to include?

Comment: That might not be ideal, but if you have an internet connection there are webbased solutions like Sharelatex and Overleaf...

Comment: With a minimal set of packages selected, [TeX Live Portable](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable) may do the trick.